# Notification icon in Android 5.0

Tags: java, android, notifyicon

Estou criando um sistema de push notification com o firebase no meu projeto.

O código que gera o push está assim:

```
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
.setContentText(messageBody)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Tudo funcionando perfeitamente, icone, mensagem, cor de fundo, porém, só até o Android Lollipop (5.0), dai pra frente só fica um circulo branco sem carregar a imagem e sem a cor de fundo.

Depois de muito pesquisar, encontrei respostas como estas:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-shown-instead
3. https://blog.clevertap.com/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/

Mas nenhum deles realmente me ajudou, uma das respostas diz para fazer uma validação da SDK, assim:

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.icon_silhouette : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

Mas não fala nada em tamanhos, sobre o que preciso fazer pra que funcione acima da SDK do Lollipop.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

Comment: O link 3 dá a resposta.

Comment: Estranho, pelo que entendi ele diz pra fazer o png de cor branca com fundo vazado só, mas eu sempre fiz todos os ícones de notificação assim, e não funciona por nada do 5.0.1 em diante.

Comment: Nunca testei em 5+, mas o que percebo é que tudo o que não seja transparente é colocado a branco. Leia a nota no [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_icon) por debaixo da palavra "source"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partir do Android Lollipop (5.0), o Google fez uma "pequena" alteração no estilo dos ícones, para que permaneça padrão em uma única cor ([e foi alertado que aplicações anteriores sofreriam alterações](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html)). Acredito que justamente por questão de elegância do Sistema, explorando mais do [Material Design](https://material.google.com/), deixando tudo "chapado". Então se você não fizer esse tratamento e usar o `ic_launcher`, o próprio sistema ajustará as cores conforme os padrões 5.0. O ideal é fazer desta forma abaixo, como você mostrou na pergunta:

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.icon_silhouette : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

Sendo então `R.drawable.icon_silhouette` utilizando uma única cor com extensão `.png`, no qual aparecerá na sua notificação como mostra [nesta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432203/2570426):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tamanho ideal do `icon_silhouette` é 24x24dp, sendo:

```
mdpi    @ 24.00dp   = 24.00px
hdpi    @ 24.00dp   = 36.00px
xhdpi   @ 24.00dp   = 48.00px
```

### Alterar cor do ícone

Na documentação em [alterações de comportamento do Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html), diz que a partir do Lolipop, com o uso do estilo Material Design, o desenvolvedor deve seguir as seguintes recomendações:

> - Use [setColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setColor(int)) para definir um cor de realce em um círculo atrás
>     da imagem do ícone.
> - Atualize ou remova ativos que envolvam cor. O sistema ignora todos os
>     canais não alfa em ícones de ação e no ícone de notificação principal.
>     Você deve presumir que esses ícones serão somente alfa. O sistema
>     desenha ícones de notificação e ícones de ação em cinza escuro

Todas as instruções relativas ao `NotificationIcon` são fornecidas em [Orientação de notificações do Google Developer](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#).

#### Detalhes

- [Patterns Notifications](https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#)
- [Style Icons](https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#)

Comment: Valeu Cleidimar, minha dúvida tava na criação desse **icon_silhouette**, obrigado!