# NOTIFICATION_SERVICE com erro channel=null, como resolver?

Tags: android, android-notification

Eu fiz funcionar perfeitamente essa notificação no android 19 e na 21 mas não funciona na 27, 28 e 29.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

 private void openNotification(){

        Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( "msg", msg );
        intent.putExtra( "status", status );
        intent.putExtra( "time", DataTime );
        // int id = 1;
        int id = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity( getBaseContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder( getBaseContext() ).setContentTitle( "Evento de Pânico" ).setContentText( msg ).setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.panic ).setContentText( DataTime ).setContentIntent( pi ).build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify( id, notification );

}
```

Na API 29 vem uma toast de aviso:

```
            Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null 
    defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
```

quando funciona na api19 vem o seguinte:

```
Notification(pri=0 icon=7f0e0005 contentView=br.com.panico/0x109007d vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 when=1567779581326 ledARGB=0x0 contentIntent=Y deleteIntent=N contentTitle=16 contentText=19 tickerText=N kind=[null])
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Configuração do NotificationCompat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/403040/3774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso deve esta ocorrendo porque a partir do Android 8.0(API 26), você precisa informar um canal de notificação, como é dito no site do android:

> ### [Canais de notificação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels)
>
> **A partir do Android 8.0 (API de nível 26), todas as notificações precisam ser atribuídas a um canal ou não serão exibidas**. Ao categorizar as notificações em canais, os usuários podem desativar canais de notificação específicos para seu app *(em vez de desativar todas as notificações)* e podem controlar as opções visuais e sonoras de cada canal, tudo isso a partir das configurações do sistema Android *(Figura 11)*. Os usuários também podem tocar em uma notificação e mantê-la pressionada para alterar os comportamentos do canal associado.
>
> Nos dispositivos com Android 7.1 *(API de nível 25)* e versões anteriores, os usuários só podem gerenciar as notificações para apps individuais *(de fato, cada app tem apenas um canal no Android 7.1 e versões anteriores)*.
>
> [image: Figura 11. Configurações de notificação para o app Relógio e um dos canais dele]
>   <sup>**Figura 11.** Configurações de notificação para o app Relógio e um dos canais dele</sup>

Para isso você vai precisar atualizar seu código para usar o `NotificationCompat` ao invés do `Notification`, alem de ter que criar seu canal:

**Dependências:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
}
```

<sup>`28.0.0` é a versão da lib `support-compat`, pode ser que seu projeto utilize uma versão diferente dessa, pois se não estou enganado isso depende da versão do `build_sdk` ou `target_sdk` do seu projeto *(não lembro qual dos dois, mas seu Android Studio deve mostra um alerta informando)*.</sup>

**Criando canal de notificação:**

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {

    // Cria o canal de notificação para a API 26+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importancia = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "nomeDoCanal", importancia);
//                                                            ^ ID DO CANAL
        channel.setDescription("Descrição do canal");

        // Registra o canal no sistema, você não pode mudar a importância ou outros comportamentos depois disso
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

<sup>No projeto em que tive que usar algo parecido para criar o Canal de Notificação, eu fazia a criação/registro do canal dentro da `onCreate`.</sup>

**Criando a notificação usando o `NotificationCompat`:**

```
/// Criar uma Intent para abrir uma Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertDetails.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
//                                                                        ^ ID DO CANAL EM QUE A NOTIFICACAO SERA DISPARADA

        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Meu titulo")
        .setContentText("Meu texto informativo")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) /// Define a Intent que sera aberta ao clicar na notificação

        .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Referencia: [Criar uma notificação - developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Comment: Funcionou! Só uma coisa, os icone que deve aparecer na barra de status aparece uma bolinha escura. E na api 19 por exemplo aparece o icone mesmo, que é o icone da empresa que vai usar o app. Já mudei o tamanho do icone, já troquei o icone. Troquei muita coisa, mas não renderiza o icone certo.

Comment: Para esse problema do icone essa outra resposta talvez ajude - [Notification icon in Android 5.0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150034/3774) , você também pode tentar criar o icone usando o **Image Asset Studio** do Android Studio - [Criar um ícone de notificação com o Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio?hl=pt-br#creating-notification)

Comment: Se puder me ajudar com essa outra questão que está nominda :  "Location entra em looping somente acima da versão API 23 Android 6.0(Marshmallow), por que?" https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406805/location-entra-em-looping-somente-acima-da-vers%c3%a3o-api-23-android-6-0marshmallow